# How to connect android app to database

Tags: android, sql-server

I am new to android. I did some android apps before but i never used database . My question is is there a way to connect database to my app directly or do i have to make a middle ware project and a service that connect to that middle ware ?

Comment: can you not use sqlite ?

Comment: no i never used it before but i will read about it

Comment: refer to my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want your database to be stored locally, then Android works really well with SQLite. You will find all you need to know about how to work with it [in this guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Basically, create a new class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. This will handle all your database-related methods. Check the guide for more details!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite. It's a lightweight database.

How to use it in Android?
Enter this link and click "**SQLite Databases**".
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample code [here](https://github.com/rakeeb11/simpleDB).

Basically when working with Android you have the option to create your own database through the `SQLite`.

**Initializing the database and declaring tables** inside it done through the [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Other **operations such as add, insert, update and delete** are done through the [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Usually when you use the `SELECT` query you use [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) in Android, and operations including `INSERT` see [`ContentValues`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) being used.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be, where do you want the database to be located, local(database will be created in your device itself) or remote(database lies somewhere else, say, Cloud Storage) ?

If local is your answer: then Android provides a storage option with Database named `SQliteDatabase`, where database is created in your device itself, you just need to create database, create tables, then all the CRUD database operations can be performed on that database.

You can find the documentation on developer.android.com with the link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Check the tutorials:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

If remote is your answer: then a web service is need to be created, for accessing database, and that web service can be consumed in our application, using the web service url.